# Warning : 28000/1045 on x10hosting

Tags: mysql, database

I've built a website to host on x10host.com, but I'm getting an error when I go onto my homepage.

The error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user '***'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/***/public_html/***/a/include/db.php on line 2
```

Line 2 of my code is:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username_user","password","username_database");
```

My `user` and `database` are linked, and `user` has all privileges granted.

What is the reason that I'm getting the `Warning`? All data appears correct, and it works fine on my computer localhost.

**Resolved**

I found out my database password was different from the hosting account password.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct credentials? Have you tried contacting X10 support?

Comment: All credentials appear correct. I'm using the username provided by x10, and the password is my main x10 login. X10 don't have a clear support method for free hosting, just a community forum

Comment: The reason I suggested asking their support (or their community led forums) is that chances are, you'd get a better responses there as it will be from the original source.

Comment: I'll ask on there, but was hoping to get this cleared up pretty quickly if this is a simple, common error found on most hosting accounts